# how to compile Linux Kernel 4.20 for RISC-V

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, cross-compiling, riscv

I am trying to compile Linux kernel 4.20.14 for RISC-V

RISC-V port which can be found here is not updated for latest version and RISC-V foundation says that it is now part of official Linux port.

when I want to create the default config file for RISC using this command:

```
make riscv-defconfig
```

I am getting the following error:

```
 HOSTCC  scripts/basic/fixdep
make[1]: *** No rule to make target 'riscv-defconfig'. Stop.
Makefile:528: recipe for target 'riscv-defconfig' failed
make: *** [riscv-defconfig] Error 2
```

Checking

```
build_linux/linux-4.20.14/arch/riscv/configs
```

I can see that there is a defconfig, but it is not named riscv-defconfig

If I try

```
make defconfig

*** Default configuration is based on 'x86_64_defconfig'
#
# configuration written to .config
#
```

and when I run

```
make menuconfig
```

I can see that arch is set to x86 and not riscv

How can I cross compile for riscv on ubuntu 18.04 using GCC:

```
gcc (Ubuntu 7.3.0-27ubuntu1~18.04) 7.3.0
Copyright (C) 2017 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

Comment: Defconfigs use underscores not dashes but it is likely what is missing in your case is an ARCH specification, ie something like (but perhaps not exactly) `make ARCH=riscv defconfig`  You also must install a cross compiler and perhaps pass a CROSS_COMPILE or prefix option as well.   You really should be following sources and instructions specific to your unidentified board and not just riscv in general, otherwise you likely have a scope of project ahead that is probably going to require a lot of individual research, learning, and troubleshooting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This may have not worked because you used the target `riscv-defconfig` instead of the `defconfig` one - see Chris Stratton's hint in his comment.

```
ls -l arch/riscv/configs/
total 4
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user user 1641 Mar  5 11:59 defconfig
```

The set of commands hereafter were able to build a 4.20.14 kernel for riscv, using a Bootlin 'bleeding-edge'toolchain:

```
wget https://toolchains.bootlin.com/downloads/releases/toolchains/riscv64/tarballs/riscv64--glibc--bleeding-edge-2018.11-1.tar.bz2
wget https://cdn.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/v4.x/linux-4.20.14.tar.xz

tar jxf riscv64--glibc--bleeding-edge-2018.11-1.tar.bz2
tar Jxf linux-4.20.14.tar.xz

export CROSS_COMPILE=$(pwd)/riscv64--glibc--bleeding-edge-2018.11-1/bin/riscv64-buildroot-linux-gnu-
cd linux-4.20.14
make ARCH=riscv mrproper defconfig

make  ARCH=riscv defconfig
  CLEAN   .
  CLEAN   arch/riscv/kernel/vdso
  CLEAN   arch/riscv/kernel
  CLEAN   usr
  CLEAN   .tmp_versions
  CLEAN   scripts/basic
  CLEAN   scripts/dtc
  CLEAN   scripts/kconfig
  CLEAN   scripts/mod
  CLEAN   scripts
  CLEAN   include/config include/generated arch/riscv/include/generated
  CLEAN   .config .config.old
  HOSTCC  scripts/basic/fixdep
  HOSTCC  scripts/kconfig/conf.o
  YACC    scripts/kconfig/zconf.tab.c
  LEX     scripts/kconfig/zconf.lex.c
  HOSTCC  scripts/kconfig/zconf.tab.o
  HOSTLD  scripts/kconfig/conf
*** Default configuration is based on 'defconfig'


make ARCH=riscv all 
 UPD     include/config/kernel.release
  WRAP    arch/riscv/include/generated/uapi/asm/setup.h
  WRAP    arch/riscv/include/generated/uapi/asm/unistd.h
  WRAP    arch/riscv/include/generated/uapi/asm/bpf_perf_event.h
  WRAP    arch/riscv/include/generated/uapi/asm/errno.h
  WRAP    arch/riscv/include/generated/uapi/asm/fcntl.h
  WRAP    arch/riscv/include/generated/uapi/asm/ioctl.h
  WRAP    arch/riscv/include/generated/uapi/asm/ioctls.h
  WRAP    arch/riscv/include/generated/uapi/asm/ipcbuf.h
  WRAP    arch/riscv/include/generated/uapi/asm/mman.h
  WRAP    arch/riscv/include/generated/uapi/asm/msgbuf.h
  WRAP    arch/riscv/include/generated/uapi/asm/param.h
  WRAP    arch/riscv/include/generated/uapi/asm/poll.h
  WRAP    arch/riscv/include/generated/uapi/asm/posix_types.h
  WRAP    arch/riscv/include/generated/uapi/asm/resource.h
  WRAP    arch/riscv/include/generated/uapi/asm/sembuf.h
  WRAP    arch/riscv/include/generated/uapi/asm/shmbuf.h
  WRAP    arch/riscv/include/generated/uapi/asm/signal.h
  WRAP    arch/riscv/include/generated/uapi/asm/socket.h
  WRAP    arch/riscv/include/generated/uapi/asm/sockios.h
  WRAP    arch/riscv/include/generated/uapi/asm/stat.h
  ...
  CC      lib/win_minmax.o
  CC      lib/xarray.o
  GEN     lib/crc32table.h
  CC      lib/crc32.o
  AR      net/ipv6/built-in.a
  AR      net/built-in.a
  AR      lib/lib.a
  EXPORTS lib/lib-ksyms.o
  AR      lib/built-in.a
  GEN     .version
  CHK     include/generated/compile.h
  AR      built-in.a
  LD      vmlinux.o
  MODPOST vmlinux.o
  KSYM    .tmp_kallsyms1.o
  KSYM    .tmp_kallsyms2.o
  LD      vmlinux
  SYSMAP  System.map
  OBJCOPY arch/riscv/boot/Image
  Building modules, stage 2.
  MODPOST 10 modules
  GZIP    arch/riscv/boot/Image.gz
  CC      crypto/crypto_engine.mod.o
  CC      crypto/drbg.mod.o
  CC      crypto/echainiv.mod.o
  CC      crypto/hmac.mod.o
  CC      crypto/jitterentropy_rng.mod.o
  CC      crypto/sha256_generic.mod.o
  CC      drivers/char/hw_random/rng-core.mod.o
  CC      drivers/crypto/virtio/virtio_crypto.mod.o
  CC      drivers/video/backlight/lcd.mod.o
  CC      fs/nfs/flexfilelayout/nfs_layout_flexfiles.mod.o
  LD [M]  crypto/crypto_engine.ko
  LD [M]  crypto/drbg.ko
  LD [M]  crypto/hmac.ko
  LD [M]  crypto/echainiv.ko
  LD [M]  crypto/jitterentropy_rng.ko
  LD [M]  drivers/video/backlight/lcd.ko
  LD [M]  crypto/sha256_generic.ko
  LD [M]  drivers/char/hw_random/rng-core.ko
  LD [M]  fs/nfs/flexfilelayout/nfs_layout_flexfiles.ko
  LD [M]  drivers/crypto/virtio/virtio_crypto.ko

ls -l vmlinux
-rwxrwxr-x 1 user user 11134176 Mar  8 08:57 vmlinux
```

Comment: @mans Just a quick question, on which dev board are you trying to run this kernel?